# C++ Method Inheritance Help

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I have a `Graphic` class that handles the drawing of an `Item`, and so all of my `Item` classes will inherit it.

In essence, I have a `Graphic::Draw(type argX, type argY)` method, that requires `argX` and `argY` to be passed to it by the `Item` method.

So think I could easily have an `Item::DrawMe()` method like this:

```
class Graphic {
    ...
    void Draw(type argX, type argY)
    {
        // drawing code
    }
    ...
}


class Item : public Graphic {
    ...
    type mX;
    type mY;
    ...
    void DrawMe() : Draw(this->mX, this->mY) { }
    ...
};
```

But I would rather have the `Item::DrawMe()` method named `Item::Draw()` instead. However, then the `Item::Draw()` method would then have the same name as the `Graphic::Draw` method. But I can't use a `virtual` base method, because I don't want to overwrite the body of the function obviously...

So how should I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can name the function `Item::Draw()` with no problem.  It won't interfere with `Graphic::Draw(type, type)`, because even though the functions have the same name, they have a different signature (i.e. different parameters)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having multiple methods named the same thing *providing* the method signature is different, i.e., the arguments are different.  In this case, the `Graphic::Draw()` and `Item::Draw()` methods have different arguments, so there is no problem.

Comment: Also, you're using constructor initialization-list syntax to call your base class function `Draw`, which is not valid syntax.  You need to call the base class `Draw` within the function body (i.e. between the `{` and `}`)

Comment: Folks, It wouldn't be a problem if they **did** have the same signature...  They are in different classes...  (Though regardless of whether the signatures match or not, there will be shadowing (hiding) issues...  And possibly compiler warnings...)

Answer (score 1):

You could just scope the child's invocation of ***Draw*** to call ***Graphic::Draw(type,type)*** explicitly...  E.g.:

```
class Graphic {
    ...
    virtual void Draw(type argX, type argY)
    {
        // drawing code
    }
    ...
}


class Item : public Graphic {
    ...
    type mX;
    type mY;
    ...
    virtual void Draw() { Graphic::Draw( this->mX, this->mY ); }
    ...
};
```

But watch out for ***Item::Draw(void)*** shadowing (hiding) ***Item::Draw(type,type)***.  You won't see both overloads in the child class (e.g. ***Item*** objects).  You'd have to use explicit scoping...  (Like ***ItemObject->Graphic::Draw(x,y)***.)  Or possibly a *"using"* clause...

Also, you run into coding complexities with respect to polymorphism...  It's nice to refer to a set of *Graphic* objects via a single *virtual Draw()* method.  E.g.: Item i;  Graphic * g = & i;  g->draw(foo,bar);

What I would suggest would be something along the lines of:

```
class Graphic {
    ...
    virtual void Draw(type argX = LOADDATA, type argY = LOADDATA)
    {
       if ( argX == LOADDATA )  argX = getArgX();
       if ( argY == LOADDATA )  argY = getArgY();

        // drawing code
    }
    virtual type getArgX() { return DEFAULT_ARGX; }
    virtual type getArgY() { return DEFAULT_ARGY; }
    ...
}


class Item : public Graphic {
    ...
    type mX;
    type mY;
    ...
    virtual type getArgX() { return mX; }
    virtual type getArgY() { return mY; }
    ...
};
```

Of course, you'd be better off migrating ***type mX*** and ***type mY*** into the base class to begin with...  Presumably most ***Graphic*** objects will have an ***x,y*** location...

Comment: this seems fairly good too. however, I'm going to go with the what was talked about on the comments on the OP. but this is still useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No way around it since you need different functionality for each child `Draw`, if you can't use `virtual` then you'll have to pick separate names for the parent and child functions. Just name the parent function `DoDraw` and the child `Draw`.